# Connect PHP to a Google Sheets file

Tags: php, database, google-sheets

Through PHP, is there a way to connect to a Google Sheets data? We have a project wherein we need to update (almost-daily) prices via CSV uploads and it's starting to become a liability to access the MySQL server of the site, truncate the contents and upload the new ones. Although the approach of uploading through the front-end came to my mind, it's much more appealing to me to have a live price update rather than uploading.

PS: Can't use an API since it's based on an offline price updates.

Comment: I don't get how google sheet can be 'offline' ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet the prices are offline. If they are online, I would use an API for a tracker

Answer (score 0):

There are google sheet plugins which allow users to pull data into google sheets directly from a database.

Comment: Was wondering if I can do the opposite way. Google Sheets becomes the database and I'll call the data through PHP